# Format strings from array in form of table on ListView Adnrodi

Tags: android, arrays, string, listview

I want to populate ListView from arraylist of strings. I have:

```
color1,color2,color3,color4               --> array1
item1,item2                               --> array2
size1                                     --> array3
id1,id2,id3                               --> array4
information1, information2, information3  --> array5
```

I want to make ListView looks nice like this:

```
color1            color2            color3            color4       ->ListView item 1
item1             item2                                            ->ListView item 2
size1                                                              ->ListView item 3
id1               id2               id3                            ->ListView item 4
information1      information2      information3                   ->ListView item 5
```

How can I join strings from array and populate ListView to be similiar to table?

I tried with this code, but it's not working well:

```
for (int m=0;m<values.size();m++) {
    element += String.format("%50s", values.get(m));
}
```

Comment: you can use multi dimensional array for generating this data structure

Answer (score 0):

There's a long and a short answer.

Short: inflate a pre-defined xml (nested TextViews inside a Linear Layout) formatted to your liking as a table inside your adapter.

Long: create your own class (preferably an ArrayList containing 5 String variables), modify an Adapter to read from your class and display each String in one of the pre-inflated TextViews (from your pre-defined xml table element) and populate a List, and call the whole thing in your activity under the "onCreate" method.

If you didn't understand any of the terms I've mentioned, get to googling (tutorials etc). AFAIK, there's no easier way...